# Is it possible to place an image off the edge of the window that doesn't affect the scroll bars?

Tags: html, css, image

I am attempting to place an image off to the side that only appears on large widescreen monitors. I am currently using this tag which places it perfectly:

```
<img src="image.png" style="position: absolute; left: 1400px;">
```

This places it exactly where I want it to go. The only problem is that it affects the scroll bars so a user on a smaller screen can scroll over and see it. What I want is for the image to be placed on top of the background and only be visible if someone has a very wide monitor.

Edit: The screen is actually using 3 images. a tiled wood background image, a map.png that is 1200px wide and a coffeecup.png image that I want sitting off to the side of the map that is only visible on large screen monitors.

Comment: If there's no other content at that position and this is just a stylistic choice then you can just prevent scroll. Otherwise you can always use js to check the page dimensions and only render the image if the viewport width is greater than some value

Comment: thanks but that's not quite what I want. users should still be able to scroll. I have a map sitting on a table that is 1200px wide. the users need to be able to scroll around the map. however on large screens, there's an empty space to the right of the map. I want to place an image in that space that only appears on large screens. hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code in question, so that I can reproduce your problem?

Comment: use that image as a second background-image : `background:url(map.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat, url(offsetimg.jpg)  1400px 0  no-repeat;` or just as a single background-image (whatever :) )  It will only show if the container is wider than 1400px

Comment: @G-Cyrillus that nailed it! post the answer if you like and I will give it a correct answer checkmark. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your image as a background-image if it's only about styling.

You can offset it of 1400px from the left  .

basicly:

`background: url(offsetimg.jpg)  1400px 0  no-repeat;`

or if you have already one, you can add it :

`background:url(map.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat, url(offsetimg.jpg)  1400px 0  no-repeat;`

It will show if the container is wide enough.

Comment: perfect! I ended up using the map image as a regular html image. Then the wood tiling and coffee cup as background images as you mentioned. `background: url('coffee.png') 1400px 200px no-repeat, url('woodtile.png') 0 0 repeat scroll;`